# Hosting MVC Application in Amazon AWS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-ec2

I have already bought a domain with Godaddy and I wish to host that in Amazon AWS. Currently I have Free AWS account and will use that.
I have Asp.net MVC application and I will use the Visual Studio AWS kit to publish to Amazon. But when publishing to aws it gives the path as amazon elastic domain but my domain.
How to host my domain in AWS and host a Asp.net Site

Comment: If you are using the visual studio kit to push to Amazon, does that mean you are using Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: @Techonthenet You just need to point your domain to AWS name server in order to host your domain. If you have problems, you can contact AWS support team

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

The solution is to create AWS hosted zone in AWS Route 53 following the steps below:

1. Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the Amazon Route 53
   console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/route53/.
2. Choose **Create Hosted Zone.**
3. Specify `Domain Name` as your custom domain name from GoDaddy (or other domain name provider)
4. Log into domain provider and find Advanced DNS options
5. Update `NameServers` in your domain provider to be the same as the ones provided by AWS after creating the Hosted Zone in step 3 (This step will take a while to propagate)
6. Return to AWS route 53 and in your new hosted zone choose **Create Record Set**
7. Specify `Name` as `www`, `Type` as `A-IPv4 address` and `value` as the public IP for the EC2 instance created by Elastic Beanstalk for your application (Since you are deploying to Elastic Beanstalk from VS) Note: If you navigate to this IP in your browser it will load your application webpage
8. Set up other Alias records as needed

Please reference this similar [question](https://serverfault.com/q/560552) and [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HwZ3wNaM69s) for more information.

Comment: This video shows we can create our own nameservers. Or I miss something

Comment: It doesnt look like the link to the video was included in the comment.

Comment: Yes, these steps are referenced in the question linked, However, I will update my answer for clarity! Thanks